# Why am I unable to access my custom module's url?

Tags: php, magento, magento2

So, I have the frontName in routes defined as ICA and my controller folder is Index as well as the controller class name. Inputting 'magento2/ICA/index/index' returns a 404 not found. Not sure what I am missing

routes:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:App/etc/routes.xsd">
<router id="standard">
    <route id="ICA_Route" frontName="ica_deliveries">
        <module name="ICA_HelloWorld"/>
    </route>
</router>
```

controller class:

```
<?php

namespace ICA\HelloWorld\Controller\Index;

use Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context;

class Index extends \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action
{
protected $_resultPageFactory;

public function __construct(Context $context, \Magento\Framework\View\Result\PageFactory $resultPageFactory)
{
    $this->_resultPageFactory = $resultPageFactory;
    parent::__construct($context);
}

public function execute()
{
    $resultPage = $this->_resultPageFactory->create();
    return $resultPage;
   }
}

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use below URL structure for execute your controller
`www.domain.com/frontName/actionpath/actionclass/`